# Merge duplicate URLs into 1 URL, Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, url, duplicates, textarea

I have function, which shows / outputs the urls from the textarea. At the moment however it won't merge duplicates into 1 URL. How can I output same urls as one (Merge http://google.com, www.google.com, http://www.google.com, or just google.com)?

**At the moment:**

[image]

**Should be:**

[image]

**My Code:**

```
let result = $("#converted_url");

$("#textarea").on("input", function() {
    result.html(""); // Reset the output

    var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
    $("#textarea").val().replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
      var link = '<div><a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a></div>';

      // Append the new information to the existing information
      result.append(link);
    });
});
```

.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<div id="converted_url"></div>
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bmw0zt7d/)

**Credits**

Scott Marcus, Stackoverflow

Comment: Will there always be a http:// in front of an URL?

Comment: would be great if it would automatically detect and merge http:/google.com and www.google.com or just google.com (as all 3 are the same website) if thats possible.

Comment: Can you please add all posible URL's in your question if it's important to filter just for one URL out of different posibilities -> 'with and without www.'
'http:/www.foo.com'
'http:/foo.com'
'https:/foo.com'
'https:/www.foo.com'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let result = $("#converted_url");

$("#textarea").on("input", function() {
    result.html(""); // Reset the output
    
    var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,})/g;
     var found = [];
    $("#textarea").val().replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
    var link = "";
     var protOmmitedURL = url.replace(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?/i, "").split('/')[0];
        if (found.includes(protOmmitedURL)) {
      return;
    }else
    {
      link = '<div><a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a></div>';
      found.push(protOmmitedURL);
    }
     
      // Append the new information to the existing information
      result.append(link);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
(Just type anything in the box to trigger the event.)<br>
<textarea id="textarea">http://google.com blah blah http://facebook.com</textarea>

<div id="converted_url"></div>
```

Comment: Try this as well. i have tried to handle some basic stuff.

Comment: Thank you very much waleed. This is exactly what I looked for :)

Comment: Just one more question. How can I also detect links such as facebook.com (without www and https) ?

Comment: you can use regex to find index of protocols as well. As your URL is a string.

Answer (score 2):

Simple fix: store matched urls in array and append link only if url is not present in that array.
UPDATE: changed regex to `/((https?:\/\/|www\.|\/\/)[^\s]+)/g` so it matches links starting with `http://`, `https://`, `www.`, `//`. You may use any other regex covering other cases (like `http://www.`) just modify stored url so that you'll be able to compare it (you may want to treat `http` and `https` link as unique).

```js
let result = $("#converted_url");

$("#textarea").on("input", function() {
  result.html(""); // Reset the output

  var urlRegex = /((https?:\/\/|www\.|\/\/)[^\s]+)/g;
  var found = [];
  $("#textarea").val().replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
    let trimmedUrl = url.replace(/^(https?:\/\/|www\.|\/\/)/, "");
    if (found.includes(trimmedUrl)) {
      return;
    }
    found.push(trimmedUrl);
    var link = '<div><a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a></div>';

    // Append the new information to the existing information
    result.append(link);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
(Just type anything in the box to trigger the event.)<br>
<textarea id="textarea">http://google.com blah blah http://facebook.com</textarea>

<div id="converted_url"></div>
```

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the problem. If you type http://google.com and http://www.google.com both will be shown.

Comment: @JonathanStellwag Question is about not displaying duplicates, not about using regex to match possible urls

Comment: Well I asked him in an commend and the owner ment to filter for every possible URL for a specific domain which in case is quite hard. If this answer fit's for him it's ok :)

Comment: Hello Jonathan, It would be great it this would work but its not nessesary. I just need to show just one url / array. So if there are exact same duplicates, it should detect that and output it just once. If that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry didn't see the answer above, my fault. This works perfect thank you very much for your help Jonathan :)

Comment: @brox I've edited it sligtly to take into account more prefixes

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your help :)